# SQL - один IF (условие), два значения

Tags: mysql, sql

Как выполняется одно условие понятно. Можно ли в одном условии, менять 2 значения? Или только 2 if использовать? Условие одно - значения нужно менять два. Два поля в одной записи.

Comment: В смысле два поля в одной записи или одно и то же поле в двух записях?

Comment: Два поля в одной записи да.

Comment: `if условие begin set f1 = 1  set f2 = 2 end`

Comment: `update table1 set field1 = 1, field2 = 2 where условие`  (если update)

Comment: Условие - в процедуре/функции или в UPDATE-запросе? IF - это function или statement?

Comment: Insert on duplicate key update.  В update получается условие стоит. If statement.

Comment: *Insert on duplicate key update* Тогда без вариантов две отдельных IF(). *If statement.* В запросе - не бывает. Только в compound statement.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.